# Google product search or AutoML for the Search product by image

Tags: image-recognition, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

I want to develop the search a product by image in android/ios app. I have some product and i want to upload some images for every product. Clients can take a photo from app and search the product from app.
I found [**google product search**](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs) but i am not sure because i tested **AutoML** and it works.
Api vision accepts only **homegoods, apparel, toys** for product search.
Does it mean it doesnt work well with other categories?
For **AutoML** you can train with your images and how it works with product search?
A product have 1 or many images but i didnt see if there is a train or model. 
Can you advice me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the category "general-v1" and see whether it works for your use case.

You don't have to train a model with Product Search you just have to wait ~30 minutes for the images to get indexed. You can GET the ProductSet to check when it was last indexed.

After it is indexed, you can search for Products in your ProductSet: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching